# Java HtmlUnit - can't login to wordpress

Tags: htmlunit, apache-httpclient-4.x

I'm trying to use HtmlUnit to login to my local wordpress website but it seems to have a cookies issue.

That's that begining of the code:

```java
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
HtmlPage loginPage = webClient.getPage("http://localhost/flowersWp/wp-admin");
HtmlForm form = loginPage.getFormByName("loginform");
```

That's what I get in the log. Anyone has an idea?
Thanks.

> Nov 27, 2010 12:43:35 PM
>   org.apache.http.client.protocol.ResponseProcessCookies processCookies
>   WARNING: Cookie rejected: "[version: 0][name:
>   wordpress_2418eeb845ebfb96f6f1a71ab8c5625a][value: +][domain:
>   localhost][path: /flowersWp/wp-admin][expiry: Fri Nov 27 12:43:35 IST
>   2009]". Illegal path attribute "/flowersWp/wp-admin". Path of origin:
>   "/flowersWp/wp-login.php"

Answer (score 7):

WebClient is using apache httpclient, so it is an HttpClient problem.

From my experience, it has to do with redirections. I've gotten rid of this problem using HttpClient and registering my own cookie support:

```java
  // Create a local instance of cookie store
  CookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();

  // Bind custom cookie store to the local context
  httpclient.setCookieStore(cookieStore);
  CookieSpecFactory csf = new CookieSpecFactory() {
      public CookieSpec newInstance(HttpParams params) {
          return new BrowserCompatSpec() {
              @Override
              public void validate(Cookie cookie, CookieOrigin origin)
              throws MalformedCookieException {
                // Oh, I am easy.
                // Allow all cookies
                log.debug("custom validate");
              }
          };
      }
  };
  httpclient.getCookieSpecs().register("easy", csf);
  httpclient.getParams().setParameter(
       ClientPNames.COOKIE_POLICY, "easy");
```

Well, in HtmlUnit I have no direct access to httpclient, but I'm thinking of changing its source code to do so, as I need to connect to wordpress with JavaScript support.

Comment: Yeah this code might be good for HttpClient but I also want to have it  working on HtmlUnit... :)

Comment: Let me know in case you make it there ;)

Comment: Well, I've succeeded in forcing cookie support, but it gived me nothing becouse of JavaScript processing errors.
Simply WebClient wrongly processed JavaScript from wordpress i was using (blog.com)....

Comment: I've just registered my 'easy' policy in HttpWebConnection class, and added parameter to WebClient to activate it.

It's an ugly workaround, not solution, so it's not applicable in my opinion for commit. However, I have created diff, I can publish it eventually.

Comment: Can someone please explain to me.. how to activate that piece of code ?!I have HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(); HttpGet get = new HttpGet(link); .... But I it does not find the function setCookieStore() and getCookieSpecs() for the client ?!

Answer (score 0):

I must note that in HttpClient 4+, I had to do the following:

```
        CookieSpecProvider csf = new CookieSpecProvider() {
            @Override
            public CookieSpec create(HttpContext context)
            {
                return new BrowserCompatSpec() {
                    @Override
                    public void validate(Cookie cookie, CookieOrigin origin)
                        throws MalformedCookieException
                    {
                        // Allow all cookies
                    }
                };
            }
        };

        RequestConfig requestConfig = RequestConfig.custom()
            .setCookieSpec("easy")
            .build();

        httpclient = HttpClients
            .custom()
//          .setHostnameVerifier(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER)
            .setDefaultCookieStore(cookieStore)
            .setDefaultCookieSpecRegistry(RegistryBuilder.<CookieSpecProvider>create()
                                              .register(CookieSpecs.BEST_MATCH, csf)
                                              .register(CookieSpecs.BROWSER_COMPATIBILITY, csf)
                                              .register("easy", csf).build())
            .setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfig)
//          .setSSLSocketFactory(sslsf)
            .build();
```