# Android: Handle Cookie from HTTP Get-Request

Tags: android, http, cookies, http-get, httpcookie

I am working on an app which shall log in to a web site (via http://......?password=xyz).
I use DefaultHttpClient for this.
Along with the GET response, the website sends a cookie, which I want to store for further POST requests.

My problem is that `client.getCookieStore().getCookies()` always receives an empty list of cookies.

If I open http://www.google.com (insted of my intended website), I receive the cookies properly, but the website I am working with, seems to send the cookie in some other way (it's a MailMan mailing list moderating page)

I can see the respective cookie in Firefox cookie manager, but not in Firebug network/cookie panel (why?). InternetExplorer HttpWatchProfessional however shows the cookie when recording the traffic....

There is some small difference, I observed between the cookies www.google.com sent and my target website: In HttpWatchProfessional, those cookies from google are marked as "Direction: sent", while the cookie from my website are marked as "Direction: Received".
(how can the google cookies be sent, while I cleared browser/cookie cache just before?)

Can someone explain the difference to me?

My code is the following:

```
DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
HttpResponse execute = client.execute(httpGet);
List<Cookie> cookies = client.getCookieStore().getCookies();
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Accept All Cookies via HttpClient](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8279970/accept-all-cookies-via-httpclient)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After further investigation, I found out that the cookie was received, but actually rejected by the httpclient, due to a path the cookie, which differed to that from the called URL.

I found the solution at:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8280340/1083345