# Is it possible in android 4.1 or in any versions to fetch the browser cookie name/value through an android app

Tags: android

Is it possible in android 4.1 or in any versions to fetch the browser site cookie name/value through an android app. If yes please provide the steps or links.

Comment: is this link clear your needs http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9956917/android-handle-cookie-from-http-get-request http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10814462/how-to-get-cookie-in-httpurlconnection-to-using-cookiestore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by "browser site cookie" you mean "cookies held by some Web browser application that you did not write", then, no, that is not possible, for obvious privacy and security reasons.

Comment: Thanks. But is it possible to get the cookie name from a sample html site written by me?

Comment: @user1616471: Yes, if you write your own browser.

Comment: Please look out the code below. I need the app to work for my own browser.

Comment: Is it possible to achieve the same through android with phonegap? If yes means, can you please provide some guide/code?