# Android : Cookies Rejected while working with HMP server (DIALOGIC)

Tags: android, json, http, httpwebrequest

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Accept All Cookies via HttpClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8279970/accept-all-cookies-via-httpclient)

I am working with HMP server, I am trying to send and get the data to hmp server with IP address 192.168.1.1.. I am getting below warning and unable to get data of the system through HMP server..

Here is the warning which i m getting.

```
05-23 13:24:06.993: W/ResponseProcessCookies(1362): Cookie rejected:"BasicClientCookie[version=1,name=visit,domain=.146.152.86.82,path=/,expiry=Wed May 23 13:34:06 IST 2012]". Domain attribute ".146.152.86.82" violates RFC 2965: effective host name does not domain-match domain attribute.
 05-23 13:24:07.123: W/System.err(1362): org.json.JSONException: No value for scalars
 05-23 13:24:07.133: W/System.err(1362):    at   org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:354)
 05-23 13:24:07.133: W/System.err(1362):    at org.json.JSONObject.getJSONArray(JSONObject.java:544)
```

I am not understanding why its taking this 146.152.86.82.. instead of this 192.168.1.1.. can any one help me out.

This is not a duplicate question. Thank you.