# Different result from browser and from mobile

Tags: php, android, ios, wordpress, api

We have a wordpress web page, and we want to make a little app for iOs and android from this.
So i've just made an API. The phone programmer is a freelancer, so at this time i have not her code, so this question will be devoted maybe, but maybe some of you will know the answer, if i tell, what i did.

There are several methods in this API, but all of them (except login), need an authenticated user.

So i made a request like this (now a working link):
http://anydomain.com/service/app_request.php?request=login&username=xxx&password=yyy&trid=zzz

This script start with a:

```
session_start();
include('../wp-load.php');
```

So when she call the script with proper credentials, i do the login.

```
    $creds = array();
    $creds['user_login'] = $this->getVars['username'];
    $creds['user_password'] = $this->getVars['password'];
    $creds['remember'] = false;
    if (is_ssl()) {
        $secure_cookie = true;
    } else {
        $secure_cookie = false;
    }
    $user = wp_signon($creds, $secure_cookie);
    wp_set_current_user($user->ID);
    wp_set_auth_cookie($user->ID, false, false);
    $user->data->user_registered = $this->formatDateForApp($user->data->user_registered);
    $this->response['user'] = $user->data;
```

If i am using a browser from desktop, everything is fine, user is logged in, and i could call the requests.

But when she try to use the logout request for example, script gives back, there was no user login:

```
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-includes/pluggable.php');
$user = wp_get_current_user();
if (empty($user) || empty($user->ID)) {
    $this->errorCode = NO_USER_WAS_LOGGED_IN;
    $this->errorMsg = 'No user was logged in';
} else {
    wp_logout();
    $this->response['message'] = $user->data->user_login . " logged out";
}
$this->showResponse();
```

I am not familiar with mobile development, so i don't know, how is it handle the sessions. Could it be the problem? Or could it be a cookie problem?

Another strange thing, if i call the search method (just get some post and give back the results in json), it works in browser, but when she tried to call it from the phone, she get back this for some reason:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://59.xxx.xxx.xxx" />
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Yes, i know, it seems too generally, and without her code, it will be hard to figure out what causes the problem, but maybe some of you also has this issue, and can help us. I think a lot of people developed apps like this, what needs to login, and keep user logged in.

Thank you.

**UPDATE:**
This is a funny thing, and i've never meet before a problem like this.
The developer is located in China.
I checked that IP address through a browser, and guess what: that page is redirect her to this page:

```
http://59.151.88.32/index.php?source=unicomdns
```

what is actually the mobile provider, who is blocking her request for some reason.
Solution could be a proxy, or i don't know, but now we know, it's not my service problem, and not her programs problem. This is a chines problem overall.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, at least, i found the problem. I wrote a little app, what is try to use these requests.
As i mentioned, in the browser was everything was fine.

I never tried to use net from android till now, but now i did it, and when i want to log in the user, logcat says:

07-16 12:52:42.890: W/ResponseProcessCookies(9125): Cookie rejected: "BasicClientCookie[version=0,name=wordpress_d0c0d54098055ddfb5fe7a1313b4d3b5,domain=.anydomain.com,path=/wp-content/plugins,expiry=null]". Illegal path attribute "/wp-content/plugins". Path of origin: "/service/app_request.php"

So that was thy developer can not log in the user on the phone...

Unlucky, i am not familiar with android in this depth, so i do not know the solution for this.
I've checked the cookie problem at here:
[Java HtmlUnit - can't login to wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4291241/java-htmlunit-cant-login-to-wordpress/4364330#4364330)
but now i do not know how to implement the cookie handling.