# Android httpclient cookie rejected illegal path attribute

Tags: java, android, wordpress, cookies

I'm building an android application which use httpclient to post and retrieve data to a wordpress server.

I can't send a post data because of the invalid path in the cookie. Here's the log I retrieved:

```
Cookie rejected: "BasicClientCookie[version=0,name=wordpress_654732f696815924ebd07fb96f161421,domain=[my-domain],path=/wp-content/plugins,expiry=Thu Feb 13 07:53:10 GMT+07:00 2014]".Illegal path attribute "/wp-content/plugins". Path of origin: "/api/auth/generate_auth_cookie/"

Cookie rejected: "BasicClientCookie[version=0,name=wordpress_654732f696815924ebd07fb96f161421,domain=[my-domain],path=/wp-admin,expiry=Thu Feb 13 07:53:10 GMT+07:00 2014]". Illegal path attribute "/wp-admin". Path of origin: "/api/auth/generate_auth_cookie/"
```

I've searched the forum, and tried solutions given, but it still rejects the cookie from the app. Several solutions I've tried are:

- set cookie policy

  ```
  httpclient.getParams().setParameter(ClientPNames.COOKIE_POLICY,
  CookiePolicy.BROWSER_COMPATIBILITY);
  ```
- This example ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4291241/java-htmlunit-cant-login-to-wordpress/4364330#4364330))
- [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/874903/how-can-i-force-javas-httpclient-to-accept-invalid-cookies) solution, still no result

here's my android code so far for sending http post data

```
 CookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();
        httpclient.setCookieStore(cookieStore);

        CookieSpecFactory csf = new CookieSpecFactory() {
            @Override
            public CookieSpec newInstance(HttpParams httpParams) {
                return new BrowserCompatSpec(){
                    @Override
                    public void validate (Cookie cookie, CookieOrigin origin)
                            throws MalformedCookieException{
                            Log.d("COOKIE", "force validate cookie path info: " + cookie.getPath() +
                                    ", origin: " + origin.getPath());
                    }
                };
            }
        };
        httpclient.getCookieSpecs().register("custom_validate", csf);
        httpclient.getParams().setParameter(ClientPNames.COOKIE_POLICY, "custom_validate");

        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
        if(postData != null){
            httppost.setEntity(postData);
        }

        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

I've gone through this all day, but no results. 
Can anyone help?

Comment: What about sending data as params in link?

Comment: I tried the above code its works for me, I am calling httpclient code in asyntask and hitting -http://blog.com/wp-login.php? url with my username and pwd and showing response in webview its shows me logged page. And without CookieSpecFactory  impl its shows me Cookie rject warning and keep showing login page.

Comment: By the way what url u hitting what is postdata?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try these steps:

1. you have to declare cookies list static variable on you web service call common class

   ```
   public static List<Cookie> cookies;
   ```
2. when you login get cookies from respone httpclient and assign it to static cookies list.
   // here i gave demo login request

   ```
   private void login(){
   try {
          DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
          HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
          if(postData != null){
               httppost.setEntity(postData);
           }

           HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
           try {
               cookies = httpclient.getCookieStore().getCookies();
           } catch (Exception e) {
           }
       } catch (Throwable e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
       }
   }
   ```
3. now get httpclient object base on login cookies for rest of server request.

   ```
   public DefaultHttpClient getHttpclient() {
   DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
   if (cookies != null) {
         int size = cookies.size();
         for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
             httpclient.getCookieStore().addCookie(cookies.get(i));
         }
    }

    // you have also set your extra properties of httpclient like user-agent and time etc. here
       return httpclient;
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks. httpclient and cookiestore should be made static and reused for every request made