# Missing cookie in http response in android app

Tags: java, android, cookies, httpclient

I'm trying to make a request to server using apache **HttpClient** from android app and I'm getting response without headers **Set-Cookies**.
I've tried to do same thing on desktop application and it worked, I've received all headers.
What am I doing wrong? Help me, please to fix this problem.

```
HttpClient httpclient1 = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet req1 = new HttpGet("http://www.example.com");
        req1.addHeader("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8");
        req1.addHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip,deflate,sdch");
        req1.addHeader("Accept-Language", "ru,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6,uk;q=0.4");
        req1.addHeader("Connection", "keep-alive");
        req1.addHeader("Host", "www.example.com");
        req1.addHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.131 Safari/537.36");
        String cookie = "";
        try {
            HttpResponse response1 = httpclient1.execute(req1);
            Header[] headers = response1.getAllHeaders();
            for (int i = 0; i < headers.length; i++) {
                System.out.println(headers[i] + "");
                if (headers[i].toString().startsWith("Set-Cookie: "))
                    cookie = headers[i].toString().substring(12);
            }   

            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost("http://www.example.com/1.php");
            postRequest.addHeader("Referer", "http://www.example.com/2.php");
            if (cookie.length() > 0) {
                cookie = cookie.replace(" path=/", "");
                postRequest.addHeader("Cookie", cookie);
            }

            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", "my-username"));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", "my-password"));
            postRequest.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(postRequest);
            Header[] hs = postRequest.getAllHeaders();
            for (int i = 0; i < hs.length; i++) {
                System.out.println(hs[i] + "");
            }
            System.out.println(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() + "");
            Header[] hs3 = response.getAllHeaders();
            for (int i = 0; i < hs3.length; i++) {
                System.out.println(hs3[i] + "");
            }
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.err.println("ClientProtocolException");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.err.println("IOException");
        }
```

Here's headers that I've received using android app:

```
200
Server: nginx/0.7.67
Date: Sun, 06 Jul 2014 16:25:26 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.3-7+squeeze14
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Vary: Accept-Encoding
```

And here's from desktop app:

```
302
Server: nginx/0.7.67
Date: Sun, 06 Jul 2014 16:39:55 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.3-7+squeeze14
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Location: http://www.example.com/
Set-Cookie: uid=12345; expires=Tue, 19-Jan-2038 03:14:07 GMT; path=/
Set-Cookie: pass=11111111111111111111111111111111; expires=Tue, 19-Jan-2038 03:14:07 GMT; path=/
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Length: 139
```

Comment: Not sure if someone has same reason, but I faced this issue when I was trying use app through open WiFi network, I suppose this network cut Set-Cookie header from original response. When I connected through mobile network it was ok.

Answer (score 1):

You must get access to the Headers on your Requests.

compare them.....  they will not be anything the same...

pay particular attention to the following:]

MimeType header value

Post body - what exactly happens to the form values for  "name", "password" and is the post body of the android EXACTLY what the webapp's sending.

Verify that the webapp is POST and not a GET.

> HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost

the line above is setting a collection of default, Post headers that your server is treating VERY DIFF from the destops collection of headers.

compare the respective headers, equalize them by adding/removing appropriate headers in your android app and you will get the same results from nginx....

Comment: the fragment of code in question I'm using in both applications, but I don't know why it gives different results. Maybe it's connected with specifics of Android OS, and with how it handles cookies?

Comment: you are actually not using same code. Webapp uses a browser and gets http stack from browser. Browser sets whatever headers it wants. Android , on other hand uses httpclient ( completely DIFF stack ) getting a completely DIFF set of default headers. you wont solve your problem without getting more involve in EXACT headers in each situation.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23291209/how-can-i-disable-default-request-headers-from-apache-httpclient-4

Comment: So, what do you mean, apache HttpClient method addHeader() in non-android app does not set the headers?

Comment: It does. But, what I meant is that ' new http post()' may have already set a header by default and u may not know that. Unless you display all header. You may have yo remove headers before u add them.

Comment: Removing headers didn't help, but I've found solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21432738/android-httpclient-cookie-rejected-illegal-path-attribute