# Issue with warning in java code

Tags: java, http

I have the following code in a program that I'm running from the command line:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();    

HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(strURL); 

HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
```

The problem I'm have is that the httpclient.execute(httpget) call generates the following warning:

```
Mar 13, 2011 9:09:53 PM org.apache.http.client.protocol.ResponseProcessCookies processCookies
WARNING: Cookie rejected: "[version: 0][name: JSESSIONID][value: 5D12815EFE10A7EC6BF3FB828E92E3D0][domain: www.pikefin.com][path: /JSPDataSource][expiry: null]". Illegal path attribute "/JSPDataSource". Path of origin: "/testjsp/JSPDataSource/mysqldatasource7.jsp"
```

Is there some way for me to suppress or ignore this warning?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I force Java's HttpClient to accept invalid cookies?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/874903/how-can-i-force-javas-httpclient-to-accept-invalid-cookies)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my shell script where I was executing the java program, I ended up redirecting standard error.